# Pass variables to array_multisort

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to create a multisort method. The following works but I don't know how to pass `array_multisort` the variables for `SORT_DESC`, `SORT_ASC` etc as variables so I had to use the `if` statement below. Does anyone know how to do this properly? I am using PHP 5.6.

Example:

```
twoColumnMultiSort($test, 'model', 'year','desc','asc');
```

Function:

```
function twoColumnMultiSort(&$arr, $sort1 = '', $sort2 = '', $sort1_type = 'asc', $sort2_type = 'asc')
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
        $arr_sort1[$key] = $row[$sort1];
        $arr_sort2[$key] = $row[$sort2];
    }

    $sort1_type = strtolower($sort1_type);
    $sort2_type = strtolower($sort2_type);

    if ($sort1_type == 'asc' && $sort2_type == 'asc') {
        array_multisort($arr_sort1, SORT_ASC, $arr_sort2, SORT_ASC, $arr);
    } else if ($sort1_type == 'asc' && $sort2_type == 'desc') {
        array_multisort($arr_sort1, SORT_ASC, $arr_sort2, SORT_DESC, $arr);
    } else if ($sort1_type == 'desc' && $sort2_type == 'asc') {
        array_multisort($arr_sort1, SORT_DESC, $arr_sort2, SORT_ASC, $arr);
    } else if ($sort1_type == 'desc' && $sort2_type == 'desc') {
        array_multisort($arr_sort1, SORT_DESC, $arr_sort2, SORT_DESC, $arr);
    }

    array_multisort($arr_sort1, SORT_ASC, $arr_sort2, SORT_ASC, $arr);
    return $arr;
}
```

test:

```
$test = array(
    0 => array (
            'id' => 1,
            'model' => 'cayman',
            'year' => '2018',
            'order' => 6,
    ),
    1 =>
        array (
            'id' => 6,
            'model' => '911',
            'year' => '2012',
            'order' => 3,
        ),
    2 =>
        array (
            'id' => 3,
            'model' => 'macan',
            'year' => '2010',
            'order' => 1,
        ),
    3 =>
        array (
            'id' => 5,
            'model' => 'cayman',
            'year' => '1999',
            'order' => 3,
        ),
    4 =>
        array (
            'id' => 4,
            'model' => 'cayman',
            'year' => '2016',
            'order' => 2,
        ),
);
```

Desired change pass in sorting as variables directly:

```
$sort1_type = "SORT_DESC";
$sort2_type = "SORT_ASC";
twoColumnMultiSort($test, 'model', 'year',$sort1_type,$sort2_type);
```

and hence remove the if statement in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put quotes around the names.

```
$sort1_type = SORT_DESC;
$sort2_type = SORT_ASC;
twoColumnMultiSort($test, 'model', 'year',$sort1_type,$sort2_type);
```

Then in the function you can use them as given.

```
function twoColumnMultiSort(&$arr, $sort1 = '', $sort2 = '', $sort1_type = SORT_ASC, $sort2_type = SORT_ASC)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
        $arr_sort1[$key] = $row[$sort1];
        $arr_sort2[$key] = $row[$sort2];
    }

    array_multisort($arr_sort1, $sort1_type, $arr_sort2, $sort2_type, $arr);

    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sort options aren't special keywords, they are just constants defined by PHP so you don't have to memorise the real values, which are actually numbers.

```
echo SORT_ASC; // 4
echo SORT_DESC; // 3
```

So you can assign them to a variable or pass them to a parameter like any other value:

```
$sort1_type = SORT_DESC;
$sort2_type = SORT_ASC;
twoColumnMultiSort($test, 'model', 'year',$sort1_type,$sort2_type);
```

You can use them as the default in the function definition as well:

```
function twoColumnMultiSort(&$arr, $sort1 = '', $sort2 = '', $sort1_type = SORT_ASC, $sort2_type = SORT_ASC)
```